# PyCharm reports import errors with TensorFlow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

Since I upgraded to TensorFlow 2, PyCharm is displaying import warnings and errors for many TensorFlow modules and classes. For example, if I use the [quickstart example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/advanced) I get:

[image]

The code runs fine, so these imports are valid, but PyCharm does not think that they are.

Does anyone know how to resolve this? I didn't experience import issues with TensorFlow 1.14.

Comment: Is it possible you installed TensorFlow2 in a different virtual env than the one your PyCharm project is configured to use? Or perhaps you installed it globally, but you have your PyCharm project configured to use a virtual env? (Check "Python Interpreter" option in PyCharm quick menu).

Comment: @MykWillis I don't think so. The code runs without errors (when I run it from PyCharm), so I don't think it's a problem with the virtualenv setup.

Comment: Which PyCharm version is this? Try the latest EAP build https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/

Comment: @PavelKarateev Sorry, should have mentioned the PyCharm version. This was on 2019.2. The latest EAP build (2019.3 EAP) fixes it though. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As @PavelKarateev mentions in the comments, the latest EAP version of PyCharm (2019.3 EAP) solves this.